# How to do validation for date field in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular8, angular10

I need validation for the date field in angular8 or 10

Format- DD/MM/YYYY

## Conditions:

->First, if the user enters [32] it should show an error message because max dates are 31 only every month.

->if he enters [31/02] then again, it should show an error because February doesn't have 31 days like this for every month

->If he enters [21/01/156277] again, it should show an error because the year should contain only 4 digits at last.

->I need validation in this way

->After date and month slash symbol should apply automatically if it is not the possible user should enter manually

->please help me with this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bstzvt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-overview-example.ts

->I have written some conditions but not getting where to apply them please help me with this

Comment: Are you using a separated component for that?

Comment: No, take help of that condition and proceed forward please

Answer (score 0):

i try so much and i think find it. see this :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bstzvt-hnusdx?file=src/app/datepicker-overview-example.html

Comment: sorry validation is not working

Comment: check it again.@RevanthReddy

Comment: CHECKED sir not showing error if i type text and leap year is not working